# Access 2010 with MS SQL Server 2008 r2, VAB Code

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

here is another question:

```
Private Sub cboKundennummer_AfterUpdate()

' Kundenname aus Abfrage Kundennummer
Me.kunde_name = Me![cboKundennummer].Column(1)
Me.lieferant_name = Me![cboKundennummer].Column(3)
Me.lieferant_nummer = Me![cboKundennummer].Column(2)
Me.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

You see, i want to call a query to fill three textboxes in the Access 2010 form. When i call the query all columns are there. But when i set a breakpoint in Editor, than only Me.kunde_name = "A Name". Both other Me... = "Null"

Why that?

--> Support.microsoft:

```
Private Sub cboNames_AfterUpdate()
   Me.txtFirstName = Me![cboNames].column(1)
   Me.txtLastName = Me![cboNames].column(2)
   Me.txtTitle = Me![cboNames].column(3)
End Sub
```

Here's my SQL code:

```
SELECT A.kunde_nummer, A.kunde_name, A.lieferant_nummer, A.lieferant_name
FROM dbo_View_Teilestamm_Lieferschein AS A 
INNER JOIN dbo_tblRetoureStamm AS B 
ON A.lieferschein_nummer = B.lieferschein_nummer;
```

When i change the first Me to the second, the first work but the second don't...

Please help :-)

Greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So hello again :-)

Now I know it!!!! Yes!!! You must **create** the Combobox **manually** wiht the **Combo Box Wizard**!!! And "Store that value in this field:"!!! I was changed my TextBox into a Combobox!!! That was the fault!!! And then the code locks:

```
Private Sub cboLieferscheinnummer_Change()
    Me.txtkunde_nummer.Value = Me![cboLieferscheinnummer].Column(1)
    Me.txtkunde_name.Value = Me![cboLieferscheinnummer].Column(2)
    Me.txtlieferant_name.Value = Me![cboLieferscheinnummer].Column(3)
    Me.txtlieferant_nummer.Value = Me![cboLieferscheinnummer].Column(4)
End Sub
```

So the code populates all four textfields!!!
Thank you.

Greetz.